# How do I output joined tables correctly?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I use two tables with an inner join on 'user.ID'='email.ID'.

Every user has a name and an ID. Each email has a username, the email address itself and a corresponding userID.
It is possible for a user to have any amount of email addresses.

Usually i print out the results of my queries using:

```html
$row["name"]
```

I select the data from the DB like this:

```html
SELECT user.name AS name, user.ID as ID, email.user AS user, email.address AS address
FROM user INNER JOIN email ON user.ID=email.ID
```

I then display a table and output each user in one line.

```html
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  <table>
  .
  .
  .
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <tr>
      <td>$row["ID"]</td>
      <td>$row["Name"]</td>
      <td>$row["Email"]</td>
    </tr>
  }
}

//this snippet is shortened simplified because I use all HTML in php echoes
```

When I try to display the email adresses inside the corresponsing users result row I just get the user multiple times with a different email adress in every row.

What I want:

[image: correct_output_table.png]

What I get:

[image: wrong_output_table.png]

How do I have to select/join/group the tables and columns and how do I output them correctly?
Thanks for any help. I´ve been stuck here for days.

EDIT:

[output_with_usernames.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sewVE.png)

Comment: You should do this rearrangement of the data in the application, not in the database.

Comment: If we could see the relevant part of your code we could probably suggest a fix

Comment: Show us the code you are using to produce the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
u.name,GROUP_CONCAT(e.email SEPARATOR ',') AS email
FROM users u
JOIN emails e ON e.user_id=u.id
```

This should return:

```
| User | Email                                           |
-------|-------------------------------------------------|
| Nick | email1@mail.com,email2@mail.com,email3@mail.com |
```

Then in PHP split the email string by comma

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to group the adresses with their corresponding usernames? I added another screenshot to my question under EDIT at the end.

Comment: You could use a foreach loop in PHP to iterate through the email array? `foreach(explode(',',$row["Email"]) as $k=>$v) { echo 'Username' .($k+1) . ': ' . $v. '<br>'; } `

Comment: I managed to achieve it by grouping it like this:
GROUP_CONCAT(email.Address SEPARATOR ',') AS Address,
GROUP_CONCAT(email.Username SEPARATOR ',') AS Username

converting it into an array ike this:
$Address=explode(",", $row["Address"]);
$Username=explode(",", $row["Username"]);

and printing it like this:
for($i = 0;$i<count($Adress);$i++) {
                echo $Username[$i] .': '. $Address[$i].'<br>';
}